# Using Klein PHP to access routing parameters

Tags: php, url, routes

I am trying to offer an an endpoint to the API I am building that accepts routing parameters.Something like:

```
example.com/api/endpoint.php/param
```

to allow `param` as string to act as the parameter for the call to the endpoint. So all I really need is the ability to know what the string after the slash is.

I understand to do this I need something to handle routing for me, and [Klein](https://github.com/klein/klein.php) php seems to be a popular light weight routing ... framework.

I am sure this is very simple but the documentation isn't really clear on it to me - here is what I am trying

```
$klein = new \Klein\Klein();
$results = $klein->respond(function () {
    return 'Everything';
});

print_r($results );
```

But this gives

```
    Klein\Route Object
(
    [callback:protected
] => Closure Object
        (
        )

    [path:protected
] => *
    [method:protected
] => 
    [count_match:protected
] => 
    [name:protected
] =>
```

Something obvious I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

EDIT: per @ArSeN comment I have updated to :

```
$klein = new \Klein\Klein();

$klein->respond(function () {
    return 'All the things';
});

$klein->dispatch();
```

But, nothing happens, how can I actually access and use the string that comes after / in the same way I would a get param like `$_GET['param']`

?

Comment: Did you call `$klein->dispatch();` yet?

Comment: @ArSeN I have not! How should I be doing that?

Comment: As per your updated question: There are examples in the docs you linked as well. However I think this question should stick to one topic which was why it was not returning anything.

Comment: That's a good point, however with adding dispatch... its still not returning anything (other than the string "All the things") for me?

Comment: That is exactly what it should return since your callback function says so. What else did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [on their page](https://github.com/klein/klein.php#example) you have to run `dispatch()` in order to actually "run" the router:

Combined with the first example (returning the same thing on every route) it would look like this:

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$klein = new \Klein\Klein();

$klein->respond(function () {
    return 'All the things';
});

$klein->dispatch();
```

I think where you fell into the pit is the idea that the response would be returned from your call to `respond()`, however you just have to "run" (aka dispatch) the router and the response will be returned from the application automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated to this - but... dispatch doesnt seem to actually... echo or return anything. If I need the string following the slash as a usable variable, do I need to do something extra?

Comment: Well I think I'm probably misusing this tool, I realise it is more suitable for if certain routes are put in to call functions and such, where I want to use it to pass parameters, for this I can simply use PHP $_SERVER[PATH_INFO]. Thanks for your time!